# Cannot Display KML attribute data in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I've linked a hosted KML file in to my custom Google Maps test website, the KML file is something I created from a clipped shapefile. I am struggling to view the attribute info once I have clicked on a KML feature, in my case a polygon. I opened the KML file in word pad and all of the attribute info is present. In Google Earth I can see the attribute data, in Google Maps I have to click the actual polyline of the KML data, only then does a small popup appear but there is no attribute data. I have copied the code from my JavaScript file, if you need my html and css I can copy that in too.

Please forgive my ignorance, I am a GIS tech and I have limited knowledge when it comes to scripting languages.

Thank you.

```
    // JavaScript Document

    // initialise variables
    var startLat = 53.479243;
    // initial centre of the map
    var startLong = -2.244239;
    var startZoom = 12;


    // inital scale of the map
    var my_map;
    // stores the text details for each point of interest
    var POI = new Array(15);
    // establish the main icon
    image = "POI_icon.png";
    // stores Place 'objects' in an array
    var marker_info = [];
    // marker for Town Hall
    var Town_Hall;
    // infowindow varaible
    var infowindow;

    // directions service variables
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService;




    // add weather service, toggle on and off

    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong);
        var weatherOn = true; //starts off false, weather layer is not on by default

    // setting up map options
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: startZoom,

    };

    // assigning map to its variable
    my_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_box"),
        mapOptions);
    // add weather layer in as service 
    var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
        temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS,
    });
    // setting a listener that will toggle the weather layer
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("weatherToggle"), 'click', function () {
        if (weatherLayer.getMap() != null) {
            weatherLayer.setMap(null);
        } else {
            weatherLayer.setMap(my_map);
        }
    });


    // adding KML layer
    // census Ward data
    var wardLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        preserveViewport: true, // preserve location of viewport  
        suppressInfoWindows: false,
        url: 'http://dodgerza.net23.net/GM_WARDS_Clipped_Final.kml'
        //    
    });
    wardLayer.setMap(my_map);
    // setting a listener that will toggle the ward layer
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("wardToggle"), 'click', function () {
        if (wardLayer.getMap() != null) {
            wardLayer.setMap(null);
        } else {
            wardLayer.setMap(my_map);
        }
    });




    // add traffic
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(my_map);
    // setting a listener that will toggle the traffic layer
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("TrafficToggle"), 'click', function () {
        if (trafficLayer.getMap() != null) {
            trafficLayer.setMap(null);
        } else {
            trafficLayer.setMap(my_map);
        }
    });
    // 


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



// function that creates a user-defined 'Place' object
function Place(name, url, latitude, longitude) {
    this.name = name;
    // 'this.property' is the same as 'Place.property
    this.url = url;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

// Set up the data for the Places

POI[1] = new Place('The Royal Exchange Theatre', 'www.royalexchange.co.uk', 53.4829138, -2.244502);
POI[2] = new Place('Cathedral Gardens', 'www.manchester.gov.uk', 53.485237, -2.242042);
POI[3] = new Place('Piccadily Gardens', 'www.manchester.gov.uk', 53.481049, -2.236826);
POI[4] = new Place('St. Johns Gardens', 'www.manchester.gov.uk', 53.477666, -2.252317);
POI[5] = new Place('YMCA Training', 'www.ymcatraining.org.uk', 53.48039, -2.23418);
POI[6] = new Place('Convention Complex', 'www.manchestercentral.co.uk', 53.477194, -2.24641);
POI[7] = new Place('John Rylands Library', 'www.library.manchester.ac.uk', 53.480274, -2.24876);
POI[8] = new Place('The Hidden Gem', 'www.hiddengem.catholicfaith.co.uk', 53.480185, -2.246432);
POI[9] = new Place('Manchester Art Gallery', 'www.manchestergalleries.org/', 53.47882, -2.241822);
POI[10] = new Place('Deansgate Station', 'www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations/dgt/details.html', 53.474402, -2.251033);
POI[11] = new Place('Manchester Oxford Rd. Station', 'www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations/MCO/details.aspx', 53.473961, -2.241806);
POI[12] = new Place('Manchester Piccadilly Station', 'www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations_destinations/MAN.aspx', 53.47732, -2.230718);
POI[13] = new Place('Salford Central Station', 'www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations/SFD/details.aspx', 53.48336, -2.255255);
POI[14] = new Place('Manchester Victoria Station', 'www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations_destinations/MCV.aspx', 53.487382, -2.242649);
POI[15] = new Place('NCP Parking lot 1', 'www.ncp.co.uk/', 53.479443, -2.246413);
POI[16] = new Place('NCP Parking Lot 2', 'www.ncp.co.uk', 53.479544, -2.248215);



//  ---------------------------------------

function draw_the_map() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: startZoom,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD,
        panControl: true, //make pan control visible
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT
        }, //place the pan control on the left
        zoomControl: true, //make zoom control bar visible
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT
        }, //place the zoom control on the left
        scaleControl: true, //make scale bar visible... position fixed at bottom right
        streetViewControl: true //enable street view.. position automatically appearing above zoom controls
    };

    // my_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_box"), myOptions);


    // the following code adds marker for Manchester Town Hall
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.479243, -2.244239);
    Town_Hall = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: my_map, //map object
        title: "Manchester Town Hall"
    });

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


    for (var i in POI) {
        marker_info[i] = new Object;
        desc = '<div id="content"> <B>' + POI[i].name + '</B><br/> Website:' + '<a href=http://' + POI[i].url + '>' + POI[i].url + '</div>';
        addMarker(i, POI[i].latitude, POI[i].longitude, desc);
    }
}

// function to create markers
function addMarker(i, markLat, marklong, description) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markLat, marklong);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: my_map, //map object
        title: POI[i].name, //tooltip title
        icon: image, //set icon
    });
    marker_info[i].marker = marker;
    marker_info[i].des = description;
    // create the infoWindow...
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker_info[i].marker, 'click', function () {
        if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }
        // setting the content
        infowindow.setContent(marker_info[i].des);
        // open info window
        infowindow.open(my_map, marker);

        calcRoute(marker_info[i].marker);
    });

}

// called when a Place is chosen from the radio button list
function openInfoWindow_radio(Place_number) {
    if (infowindow != undefined)
        infowindow.close();

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent(marker_info[Place_number].des);
    // open info window
    infowindow.open(my_map, marker_info[Place_number].marker);
    calcRoute(marker_info[Place_number].marker);

}

// called when the 'reset the map' button is pressed
// closes an open window and re-centres the map
function resetmap(startLat, startLong, startZoom) {
    my_map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong), startZoom);
    infowindow.close();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);

}

function calcRoute(ori_marker) {
    // intialise
    directionsDisplay.setMap(my_map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions_box"));
    var request = {
        origin: ori_marker.position,
        destination: Town_Hall.position,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,


    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google-Maps supports only a few KML-elements,

---

**Support for `<ExtendedData>` :    partially**

untyped `<Data>` only, no `<SimpleData>` or `<Schema>,` and entity replacements of the form `$[dataName]` are unsupported.

---

Unsupported elements will be ignored.

You'll find the complete list at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps

Comment: Dr. Molle - thank you. I inspected my kml in word pad, I noticed many unsupported elements. I originally converted a shapefile to KML using QGIS. How do I change these resulting unsupported elements in the KML file so that it is compatible in Google Maps? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using the `<ExtendedData/>` you may use `<description/>` and populate it with the desired HTML that should be displayed in the InfoWindow

Comment: Thank you - I took your advice and updated the <description>, I am getting some attribute info such as the name of the polygon, however no other data is visible. Should I be replacing the <SchemaData> or <SimpleData> fields too?